# Separate regex groups

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a java regex to get a (numeric space text) value but when i have a new line the value doesn´t grouped, sample

regex expression `(\d{14}\s.*\n)`

Value :

```
59105999000321 My value start
with new line number
12105999000343 AAAAAasasas asdasdasd
32105999000323 asdasxasxasx asdasd
```

the group result in https://regex101.com/ is:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-29    `59105999000321 My value start`
Group 1.    0-29    `59105999000321 My value start`
Match 2
Full match  51-87   `12105999000343 AAAAAasasas asdasdasd`
Group 1.    51-87   `12105999000343 AAAAAasasas asdasdasd`
Match 3
Full match  88-122  `32105999000323 asdasxasxasx asdasd`
Group 1.    88-122  `32105999000323 asdasxasxasx asdasd`
```

I have a regex with following result:

```
group 1 : 59105999000321 My value start
    with new line number

group 2: 12105999000343 AAAAAasasas asdasdasd

group 3: 32105999000323 asdasxasxasx asdasd
```

I expect

```
group 1 : 59105999000321 My value start with new line number 

group 2: 12105999000343 AAAAAasasas asdasdasd 

group 3: 32105999000323 asdasxasxasx asdasd
```

how i do this in java?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: group 1 : 59105999000321 My value start with new line number

group 2: 12105999000343 AAAAAasasas asdasdasd

group 3: 32105999000323 asdasxasxasx asdasd

Comment: Your regex only has 1 capturing group, so `matcher.group(0)` = whole match and `matcher.group(1)` = Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(\d{14}\s.*(?:\n*(?!^\d{14}).*)*)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B2hqjR/3)

Explanation:
Since the requirement is to match lines starting with 14 digits, a negative lookahead for the same is added after `\n*`

Comment: Good, but, I need separarate by groups and the infinite \n until another 14 digits or the last line, is possible?

Comment: please edit the Demo link with your failed cases.(After adding the strings, use the update regex link in the top left). also, could you provide more details as to what you mean by "I need separate by groups"?. Full Match and Group 1 are giving matches as you have mentioned in your post.

Comment: The Edited value 
https://regex101.com/r/B2hqjR/2
I need separate matcher 14 digits until another 14 digits or the end of text

Text value 
=================
59105999000321 My value start
with new line number
aaaa


12105999000343 AAAAAasasas
32105999000323 asdasxasxasx asdasd

weqpowepoqwiq
============

The first match

59105999000321 My value start
with new line number
aaaa

the second match

12105999000343 AAAAAasasas

the third match

32105999000323 asdasxasxasx asdasd

weqpowepoqwiq

---------------------
Do you understood?

Comment: see if `(\d{14}\s.*(?:\n*(?!^\d{14}).*)*)` works. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B2hqjR/3)

Comment: @MisterB, I have edited the answer with the regex in the last comment